# 2 nested for loops pushing into a vector, trying not to repeat the push_back value

Tags: c++

I have two nested for loops pushing into an array, I don't want to cause repetition while pushing back. Here's some code to make my question more clear:

```
int TARGET = 180;
   vector<int> dataSet;
   vector<Sublist> choices;

   dataSet.push_back(20); dataSet.push_back(12); dataSet.push_back(22);
   dataSet.push_back(15); dataSet.push_back(25);
   dataSet.push_back(19); dataSet.push_back(29);
   dataSet.push_back(18);
   dataSet.push_back(11); dataSet.push_back(13); dataSet.push_back(17);
   choices.push_back(Sublist(&dataSet));


   numSets = 1;
   foundPerfect = false;
   for (k = 0; k < dataSet.size(); k++)
   {
      for (j = 0; j < numSets; j++)
      {
         if (choices[j].getSum() + dataSet[k] < TARGET)
         {
            choices.push_back(choices[j].addItem(k));
            cout << numSets << endl;
            numSets++;
         }
         if (choices[j].getSum() + dataSet[k] == TARGET)
         {
            cout << "0" << endl;
            foundPerfect = true;
            max = j;
            break;
         }
      }
   }
```

class definition:

```
class Sublist
{
public:
   Sublist(vector<int> *orig = NULL)
      : sum(0), originalObjects(orig) { }
   Sublist addItem(int indexOfItemToAdd);
   void showSublist() const;
   int getSum() const { return sum; }

private:
   int sum;
   vector<int> *originalObjects;
   vector<int> indices;
};

Sublist Sublist::addItem(int indexOfItemToAdd)
{
   Sublist passSublist;

   passSublist = *this;

   //new sum being added

   cout << "sum added: " << (*originalObjects)[indexOfItemToAdd] << endl;
   passSublist.sum = sum + (*originalObjects)[indexOfItemToAdd];


   //new index being added into indices
   //passSublist.indices.push_back((*originalObjects)[indexOfItemToAdd]);
   passSublist.indices.push_back(indexOfItemToAdd);
   //cout << passSublist.sum << endl;
   return passSublist;
}
void Sublist::showSublist() const
{
   vector<int>::const_iterator vIter;
   if (indices.empty())
      cout << "array[" << "0" << "] = " << "EMPTY";
   for (vIter = indices.begin(); vIter != indices.end(); vIter++)
   {
      cout << "array[" << *vIter << "] = " << (*originalObjects)[*vIter] << ", ";
      //cout << this->sum << endl;
   }
}
```

Currently my choices vector is being filled with repeating indices. I'm finding the perfect sum before or equal to target using a separate statement at the end of my program with the result being:

```
array[0] = 20, array[0] = 20, array[0] = 20, array[0] = 20, array[0] = 20, array
[0] = 20, array[0] = 20, array[1] = 12, array[1] = 12, array[3] = 15, sum:179
```

array[0] should only appear once. Same with [1]. Any ideas of how to fix this please?

Here is a fully working program if anyone wants to test it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <stdio.h>


#include <algorithm>

class Sublist
{
public:
   Sublist(vector<int> *orig = NULL)
      : sum(0), originalObjects(orig) { }
   Sublist addItem(int indexOfItemToAdd);
   void showSublist() const;
   int getSum() const { return sum; }

private:
   int sum;
   vector<int> *originalObjects;
   vector<int> indices;
};

Sublist Sublist::addItem(int indexOfItemToAdd)
{
   Sublist passSublist;

   passSublist = *this;

   //new sum being added

   cout << "sum added: " << (*originalObjects)[indexOfItemToAdd] << endl;
   passSublist.sum = sum + (*originalObjects)[indexOfItemToAdd];


   //new index being added into indices
   //passSublist.indices.push_back((*originalObjects)[indexOfItemToAdd]);
   passSublist.indices.push_back(indexOfItemToAdd);
   //cout << passSublist.sum << endl;
   return passSublist;
}
void Sublist::showSublist() const
{
   vector<int>::const_iterator vIter;
   if (indices.empty())
      cout << "array[" << "0" << "] = " << "EMPTY";
   for (vIter = indices.begin(); vIter != indices.end(); vIter++)
   {
      cout << "array[" << *vIter << "] = " << (*originalObjects)[*vIter] << ", ";
      //cout << this->sum << endl;
   }
}

int main()
{
   int TARGET = 180;
   vector<int> dataSet;
   vector<Sublist> choices;
   vector<Sublist>::iterator iter, iterBest;
   int k, j, numSets, max, masterSum;
   bool foundPerfect;

   dataSet.push_back(20); dataSet.push_back(12); dataSet.push_back(22);
   dataSet.push_back(15); dataSet.push_back(25);
   dataSet.push_back(19); dataSet.push_back(29);
   dataSet.push_back(18);
   dataSet.push_back(11); dataSet.push_back(13); dataSet.push_back(17);

   choices.clear();
   cout << "Target time: " << TARGET << endl;

   cout << endl;



   choices.push_back(Sublist(&dataSet));
   /*
   choices.push_back(choices[0].addItem(5));
   choices.push_back(choices[1].addItem(2));
   choices.push_back(choices[2].addItem(4));

   vector<Sublist>::iterator iter, iterBest;
   int k, j, numSets, max, masterSum;
   bool foundPerfect;
   */

   vector<int> randIndices;
   srand(time(NULL) + rand());

   numSets = 1;
   foundPerfect = false;
   for (k = 0; k < dataSet.size(); k++)
   {
      for (j = 0; j < choices.size(); j++)
      {
         if (choices[j].getSum() + dataSet[k] < TARGET)
         {
            choices.push_back(choices[j].addItem(k));
            cout << numSets << endl;
            numSets++;
         }
         if (choices[j].getSum() + dataSet[k] == TARGET)
         {
            cout << "0" << endl;
            foundPerfect = true;
            max = j;

            iterBest = choices.begin();
            iterBest = iterBest + j;
            break;
         }
         //k++;
      }
   }

   system("pause");

   cout << "display" << endl;

   for (iter = choices.begin(); iter != choices.end(); iter++)
   {
      iter->showSublist();
      cout << "\n---sublist class sum:" << iter->getSum() << endl << endl;
      cout << "next sublist class\n" << endl;
   }


   vector<Sublist>::iterator best;
   int highestSum = 0;
   int highestSumsIndex;
   for (int q = 0; q < choices.size(); q++)
   {
      if ((choices[q].getSum() > highestSum) && (choices[q].getSum() <= TARGET))
      {
         highestSum = choices[q].getSum();
         highestSumsIndex = q;
      }
   }
   choices[highestSumsIndex].showSublist();
   cout << choices[highestSumsIndex].getSum();



   cout << "pause" << endl;
   std::system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understood you correctly, you want to have no duplicates in your `indices`. There are two options:

1. Check if the element is already there:

   ```
   if (std::find(passSublist.indices.begin(), passSublist.indices.end(), indexOfItemToAdd) != passSublist.indices.end())
       passSublist.indices.push_back(indexOfItemToAdd);
   ```

   *I do not recommend this* because you'll end up with slower insertion, since you have to iterate over potentially the entire vector first, which is basically worst-case O(n).
2. Use an `std::set` instead. This is a data structure that *has no duplicates* at the expense of the order of insertion not mattering. Include `set` at the start of your program and replace:

   ```
   vector<int> indices;
   ```

   with:

   ```
   set<int> indices;
   ```

   and replace this:

   ```
   passSublist.indices.push_back(indexOfItemToAdd);
   ```

   with:

   ```
   passSublist.indices.insert(indexOfItemToAdd);
   ```

   Also change `vector<int>::iterator vIter` to `set<int>::iterator vIter`.

   This is preferred to choice 1 because insertion time is O(log n).